# Can't center some text in a Bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to center some text in a row. I feel like this shouldn't be this difficult and I'm confused on why its not working.

Pic(Example)

[image]

```css
#title_img {
  background-image: url(http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/UserImages/4343091c-c906-457b-b885-77675c22c92f.jpg);
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#title_img_holder {
  padding-top: 5%;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#title_holder {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid" id="header_con">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="title_img_holder"> <img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/UserImages/4343091c-c906-457b-b885-77675c22c92f.jpg" class="mx-auto" alt="Smiley face" height="180" width="180"> </div>
    <div class="row" id="title_holder">
      <h2 class="text-center">We fix screens.
        <small class="text-muted">Not for free though</small>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using the most current version of boostrap 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
#title_holder h2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

(You have to center the h2 inside its parent container)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpqQYq

Comment: omg i just realized that I've been editing the one above it by accident bc of a similar name XD

Comment: also i have to wait 3 minutes before i can accept your answer but i will do it

Answer (score 1):

Right now, the `display: flex` on `.title_holder` is overriding the ability of your `<h2>` to fill the full width of its parent automatically. A simple fix would be to set `.title_holder h2 { width: 100%; }`, and the text content will then be centered.

```css
#title_img {
        background-image: url(http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/UserImages/4343091c-c906-457b-b885-77675c22c92f.jpg);
        height: 180px;
        width: 180px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    #title_img_holder {
        padding-top: 5%;
        float: none; 
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    #title_holder {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #title_holder h2 {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid" id="header_con">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" id="title_img_holder"> <img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/UserImages/4343091c-c906-457b-b885-77675c22c92f.jpg" class="mx-auto" alt="Smiley face" height="180" width="180"> </div>
                <div class="row" id="title_holder">
                    <h2 class="text-center">We fix screens.
      <small class="text-muted">Not for free though</small>
    </h2> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I already gave the check thing to him but heres a upvote, gold star, comment and I will take you advice to heart as well as a anime girl reaction img http://i.4cdn.org/b/1489612869792.jpg

Comment: Haha, appreciate it. Glad we could help.